# Python sphinx how to list functions' names of module

Tags: python, python-sphinx

How to list functions' names and summary?

Right now I have

```
.. automodule:: module_dir.module_name
   :members:
```

Which returns the whole docstring of each function, which is too much for me. Is there any option to limit output or get just functions' names?

Answer (score 0):

This part of code needs to be added to conf.py to get rid of all docstrings.

```
   def process_docstring(app, what, name, obj, options, lines):
        """
        Deletes unnecessary docstring
        """
        if what != "module":
            del lines[:]

    def setup(app):
        app.connect('autodoc-process-docstring', process_docstring)
```